# Continuity of $\varphi(f)=\int_0^1f(x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, definite-integrals, operator-theory, lebesgue-measure

I've been solving some problems from my real functional analysis course, and for some proof I've considered using an operator $\varphi$, that goes from the Hilbert space $\mathcal H=L^2((0,1))$ to $\mathbb R$ defined as
$$\varphi(f)=\int_0^1f(x)dx.$$
What I'm trying to prove is the closedness of certain set (I'll use the characterisation of closed sets by convergent sequences), but in order to be able to use that kind of arguement it's required that $\varphi$ is continuous in $L^2((0,1))$. It seems trivial, but I'm not completely sure about it.

Is is trivial that the $\varphi$ operator is continuous in $\mathcal H$? If not, how can I prove it?

Comment: Remember, for a linear functional, continuous is the same as bounded. Cauchy Schwarz inequality does the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An operator between two Banach spaces is continuous if and only if it is bounded. So we write $$\Bigg|\int_0^1 f(x) dx\Bigg| \leq \bigg( \int_0^1|f(x)|^2 dx \bigg)^{1/2} \cdot \bigg(\int_0^1|1|dx \bigg)^{1/2} =\bigg(\int_0^1|f(x)|^2dx \bigg)^{1/2} < \infty$$

since every $f$ is in $L^2$. So if $||f||_2 = 1$, then $|\varphi| < 1$ as well, and $\varphi$ is bounded with constant $1$.

Comment: I understand, that was where I needed the fact that $\mathcal H=L^2(0,1)$. But you forgot the exponent $1/2$ in the integral of $|f(x)|^2$ right? Thanks!

Comment: Yep, on both, but they're both supposed to be $1$ which is conveniently its own square root. Let me put those in.

Comment: Also, it wouldn't really matter what $L^p$ space you use. You could replace Cauchy-Schwarz with Holder with exponent $p$ and $p^\ast$, and it's still fine since $||1||_{p^\ast}$ is still $1$ for all $p$.